# How do you create a numpy matrix with strings and ints?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, numpy

I created a numpy matrix as such:

```
[[A, B, C, D, E]
 [5, 6, 8, 2, 6]
 [-2, -9, 3, 3, 6]]
```

However, when I try to add the ints in row 2 and 3 into row 4, row 2 and 3 are recognized as strings instead of ints:

```
[[A, B, C, D, E]
 [5, 6, 8, 2, 6]
 [2, 9, 3, 3, 6]
 [52, 69, 83, 23, 66]]
```

My desired output is:

```
[[A, B, C, D, E]
 [5, 6, 8, 2, 6]
 [2, 9, 3, 3, 6]
 [7, 15, 11, 5, 12]]
```

I do not want to use int(matrix[i][j]) for all the places where I'm trying to access and operate on the matrix. How do I prevent this string addition from happening, where I want an int addition?

Comment: Probably the answer would be "do not mix strings and numbers in an array" but apparently this is not what you want to hear.

Comment: Could you please add the code that you used to create these arrays?

Comment: You should also not append to a matrix unless you absolutely need to, and if you're append data, especially heterogeneous data, use a list of arrays.

Comment: Also, Numpy array is homogeneous, you can check the docs. Would normal python lists not work for you? They are heterogeneous

Comment: If you really want strings, show them as Python would, with quotes.  Otherwise your 'code' letters look like variables.  `[["A", "B", ...][1,2,...]]`.  But tell us - how do you intend to operate on the numbers?  The fast compiled math in `numpy` expects the **whole** array to be numbers, not just some rows.  Why numpy arrays instead of lists?

Comment: I think based on this advice, I will use lists instead of numpy. Thanks everyone.